# Passing multiple parameters to a single test pipeline in GitLab

Tags: java, gitlab-ci

I have a test class

```
public class MyTestClass {
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    String param = "hard-coded value";
    // the rest of the test
  }
}
```

I would like to replace the hard-coded parameters (there will be many) with variables in the GitLab CI pipeline for the test I am running. I know that using `System.getEnv(...)` works. I am trying to determine if there is a better alternative. For example, if I have 20 arguments to pass to a test, **could I pass a map instead?** It might be simpler to handle key/value pairs in the code rather than having a bunch of calls to `getEnv`.

Comment: Why do you want to pass arguments from the pipeline to the tests? Is using [`@ParameterizedTest`s  (`baeldung.com`)](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5) an option?

Comment: @Turing85 Unfortunately, that's not an option at this point.

Comment: Why not? I feel that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Turing85 Maybe this is an XY problem. But, for starters, we're are limited to JUnit 4 and, for simplicity, I would rather have key/value pairs than individual string values. The end goal is to build an XML file that's an input to an in-house testing framework we must use. Outside of that, I can't divulge much more information. But that are the constraints I am operating under.

Comment: If using `System.getEnv(...)` ain't broke, why do you want to fix it?

Comment: @Bohemian because I need mapped values, and there will be many key/value pairs I must consume for my tests to work.

Comment: Can the env var be a path to a file o' data (probably json) that you can just read in?

Comment: @Bohemian Preferably no. The idea is to dynamically build these XML files rather than have a file explosion. I would not be asking this specific question if that was an option. I know how to solve this using static files.

Comment: "*we're are limited to JUnit 4*" - [Parameterized tests are available in JUnit 4 (`github.com`)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests). I still do not understand why the input has to come from the pipleine, and cannot be provided in the test itself or in a file that is provided with the tests.

Comment: @Turing85 does it support maps? If so, I can simply delete this question. Also keep in mind that passing parameters thru the pipeline helps you build ad hoc tests.

Comment: [There seems to be a way to use maps (`ourcraft.wordpress.com`)](https://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/writing-a-parameterized-junit-test/). Not sure if this is what you want. --- Instead of deleting the question, you can also [self-answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Turing85 I will definitely give this a try. Thanks,

Comment: @Turing85 I think I found a potential solution thanks to that link you sent earlier! I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **@Turing85**, I came up with the following (potential) solution. I tested it and it works. All I need is for the rest of the team to accept it. This solution is for JUnit4, but what I could see should be very similar if using JUnit 5.

In simple terms:

1. Annotate your test class with `@RunsWith(Parameterized.class)`
2. Create a static method to create your test data (Parameters)
3. Annotate such static method with `@Parameterized.Parameters`
4. In my case, since I only need a single parameter (map), the return type for my `data()` method will be `Object[]` or `Iterable<? extends Object>`
5. Your test class constructor should take the same arguments used in the `data()` method. If the returned array or iterable object contains more than one element, the test method will iterate as many times as the returned object has elements. For the example below, `myTest()` method will execute twice: once for `map1` and once for `map2`. If this is not desirable, you can return an iterable object containing a single element.

A simplified version of this solution should look like this

```
@RunsWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestClass {
  private Map<String, String> valueMap;
  
  public MyTestClass(Map<String, String> valueMap) {
    this valueMap = valueMap;
  } 

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Object[] data() {
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("foo", "test1");
    map2.put("bar", "test1");
    return new Object[] {map1, map2};
  }
  
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    // DO YOUR TEST... for now, just show values in console
    valueMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: "  k + "; Value: " + k));
  }
}
```

If you require a more involved example, the [Parameterized](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) class contains Javadoc with multiple examples. Ultimately, following those examples were extremely informative and complimented very well the link that @Turing85 provided in the Question comments section.

Comment: Remark: If we are using Java 9+ and the map does not have more than 10 entries, we can use `Map<String, String> map1 = Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", ...);`. This has the side effect that the map created by `Map::of`is immutable.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, thank you for that observation. At home, I used Java 17 but for this project, I am restricted to Java 8 (for now).